# Spring Security Grails Geb throwing weird exception

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, geb

I am trying to use `Geb` for testing grails application having `Spring Security`. When I try to access any page from `Geb` test I got this exception

```
    ERROR org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - IllegalStateException occurred when processing request: [GET] /login/auth
The type registry TypeRegistry(id=375910915,loader=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader) does not know about type id 1925. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The type registry TypeRegistry(id=375910915,loader=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader) does not know about type id 1925
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - IllegalStateException occurred when processing request: [GET] /favicon.ico
The type registry TypeRegistry(id=375910915,loader=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader) does not know about type id 1925. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The type registry TypeRegistry(id=375910915,loader=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader) does not know about type id 1925
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Sometime it goes and some time this happens.

Comment: Looks like it tries to authenticate public resources in your application.

Comment: but why this errors is occuring. I tried an other sample application and there it is not occuring